# Jest has detected the following 1 open handle potentially keeping Jest from exiting: ● TCPSERVERWRAP

Tags: node.js, express, unit-testing, jestjs, ts-jest

I'm setting unit test for my nodejs app. To test the setup I have a very simple express route which looks as below

todo.ts

```
import { Router } from "express";
const router = Router();

router.get("/todo", async (req, res) => {
 return res.status(200); 
});

export default router;
```

Then I have created a folder _*tests* with a subfolder unit

todo.test.ts

```
/*
* @group unit
*/

import request, { SuperAgentTest } from "supertest";
import app from "../../../server";

let router: SuperAgentTest;

beforeAll(async () => {
 router = request.agent(app);
});

afterAll(async () => {
 await dbClose();
});

describe("ToDo API", () => {
 // Test Case -> 200
 it("Should return 200", async () => {
 const result = await router.get("/todo");
 expect(result.status).toEqual(200);
 });
});
```

I have the script in my package.json to run the unit tests is

`"test:unit": "jest --verbose --detectOpenHandles --group=unit",`

Now when I'm running the test from cmd/bash `npm run test:unit` I keep getting the below error

> Jest has detected the following 1 open handle potentially keeping Jest from exiting:
> ●  TCPSERVERWRAP

**What's is causing this & how to get rid of it?**

Thanks!

Comment: Don't start the express server in `server.ts`.

Comment: I have not. I have a different file app.ts for that